# IIS 7: 2 IP's and 2 SSL sites

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, ipv4

I am encountering an issue while trying to set up 2 SSL websites on a Windows 2008 Server box with IIS 7.

The machine has one primary IP address on which the first SSL website is binded (that works OK) and an additional IP v4 address that I have purchased in order to bind the second SSL site to.

I have added the additional IP address to my NIC via Propieties->Advanced->IP Addresses and binded the new website to it via IIS manager, on standard port 443. I have also added an A record pointing to this IP in the DNS server Forward Lookup zone for this website. The other site is binded to the primary IP address.

However, this new website works only intermittently. At some point it loads the website viat https and some time later it will try to fetch the other website's SSL certificate and throws a SSL error (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)

Even stranger, the website may sometime load in Firefox but not in Google Chrome.

Could you please guide me if you have encountered this behavior before?
Thank you.

Comment: so you have 2 different certificates ? Is it a SAN certificate or 2 different certificates ?

Comment: I have 2 different certificates. I solved the problem, it was with my DNS enteries.

Comment: Great. You can add it as an answer and mark is as an answer. That will help others with similar issue.